# Writing shapefile using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, qgis-3

In QGIS 3.10, 
the data for the layer SIMnodes seem to be OK
as inspected in the respective data table
but trying to save it into a shapefile:

```
cSIMnodes = QgsProject.instance().homePath() + '\\SIMnodes.shp'

QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer = SIMnodes,
       fileName = cSIMnodes,
       fileEncoding = 'UTF-8',
       destCRS = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326),
       driverName = 'ESRI Shapefile')
```

yields all real numbers in the resulting Esri shapefile to be wrong
{for example 234.5 is written as 2.0}.

All integers and all strings are written well.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, your request "QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)" doesn't work.

To export, the syntax is as follows :

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
file_path = "C:/Users/v.bre/Desktop/test/test.shp"
encoding = "utf-8"
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:2154')
format = "ESRI Shapefile"

writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer,file_path,encoding,layer.crs(),format)
```